# Scraping two drop down menus with selenium -Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all the data (using Python and Selenium) from what is some sort of a nested drop down menu, but so far I've only managed to print out values for the first drop down.

The website is in Turkish but basically my goal is to print names of all the cities (1st drop down), towns inside those cities (2nd drop down), and finally all the addresses in the resulting tables. For some reason, I can operate on the first drop down, but the second one gives me an empty result. Below is my code for reference:

```
url = ('https://camiler.diyanet.gov.tr/')
browser.get(url)
city=browser.find_elements_by_id("ctl00_ctl35_g_7c8222a9_e27f_4831_b393_65197bc417d3_drpIl")
town=browser.find_elements_by_id("ctl00_ctl35_g_7c8222a9_e27f_4831_b393_65197bc417d3_drpIlce")
# city.select_by_index(81)
for c in city :
    for t in town :
        print(c.text)
        print(t.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the second dropdown is filled **after** having selected one entry from the first one.

You can see this behaviour in the code of the first dropdown the following:

```
<select name="ctl00$ctl35$g_7c8222a9_e27f_4831_b393_65197bc417d3$drpIl" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ctl35$g_7c8222a9_e27f_4831_b393_65197bc417d3$drpIl\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ctl35_g_7c8222a9_e27f_4831_b393_65197bc417d3_drpIl" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Seçiniz">Seçiniz</option>
                    ....
```

So if you want to use selenium for this I think you need to emulate the mouse movement and click on the different entries.

For more information about the mouse actions you can look at [the doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/mouse_and_keyboard_actions_in_detail/).

Comment: I see, I thought I was doing that with the nested loop. Do you recommend anything else than Selenium? Thanks heaps!

Comment: In some cases you can reverse the API used by the frontend to get your response in an easy way just by doing a request and parsing a json or whatever it returns. 
But, in your specific case it seems that every time you select an entry from the first dropbox it perform a POST request on the same URL. You should be able to record the specific request for each city and emulate just this behaviour instead of clicking the mouse. In every case, is this worth it? Cities and towns relations usually don't change too often, so i was wondering if you can just save a json and load it every time u need